# Performing a classification if having categorial labels and a distance matrix

Tags: neural-networks, classification, random-forest, svm

I encountered a multi-class classification problem and I wonder which model would work the best in my scenario. I have around 50,000 vectors (each of size 200) with corresponding categorical labels expressed a vectors of size 500 (closer categories correspond to closer vectors). There are around 5000 distinct labels. I can compute a distance matrix between each pair (e.g. the distance between "apples" and "bananas" is 0.312).

Which model would one pick for this classification task? Would it make sense to use classical methods such as random forests or svms or they will overfit?

**EDIT:** Clarified the question due to Dave's request.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Could you please explain what you mean about the categories having a certain distance between them?

Comment: Hey @Dave. Yes. think about sentiment analysis. The phrase "I'm quite sad" is in  "11.23% negative" while "I'm extremely optimistic" is "78.1% positive". The distance between these two phrases is defined to be the euclidean distance between the a vector representing "11.23% negative" and the vector representing "78.1% positive".

Comment: I think it will be helpful to you to say the problem you aim to solve and what you’ve discussed in your question has to do with it.

Comment: @Dave I collected data about 5,000 people. For each person I have his health data, embedded as a vector of size 500 and 10 foods only he likes (each embedded as a vector of size 200). My problem is to predict given a food vector the health condition of the person. The health embeddings are like GloVe in the sense closer health conditions imply the vectors are closer to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for explaining more context and aligning me again. I'd still recommend not to pose it as a classification problem.  Because the classification will treat the 500-dimension vector as a single category which potentially waste the precious information extracted into those 500 dimensions. For example, based on the 500 dim space, health condition group A is very similar to group B, but very different from group C. such similarity will not be ignored if they are turned into group A/B/C for classification.
SNN, on the other hand, is a better idea (thx for inspiring me) since it will consider such similarity.

Comment: I have two embeddings on the same cortex, one having short vectors and one longer. I want to train a classifier that given a pair (long, short) gives the "correlation" between them as if they were in the same cortex.

Comment: I want to predict from a food vector (of size 200) a health condition vector (size 500). I just mentioned that in my dataset for every health "category" I have 10 samples. That's what I mean. I consider Siamese network which takes should take a health vector and a food vector and predict the "correlation" between them but that seems a bit in-practical to construct such a huge dataset, no?

Comment: Thx for aligning me. I'd still recommend not to pose it as a classification problem.